# Can schemes encode higher tangency information?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The canonical example of a fat point is the affine scheme $\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$. We capture additional tangency information by virtue of the fact that $\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))=(x)$ which is not the same as $(0)=\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x))$ even though they are both one point spaces. The functions on the vanishing locus of $(x^2)$ are lines whereas the functions on the vanishing locus of $(x)$ are constant. I am wondering if schemes as spectra can encode higher tangency information. The fat point $(x)$ gives us a point and a tangent line. Do we lose this information in the spectrum when we consider something like $\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^3))$? Functions over the vanishing locus of $x^3$ are quadratics, but it appears as though $\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^3))=\text{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))=(x)$. Do we only capture tangent information in the structure sheaf and not in the spectrum?

Comment: Look online for "jet spaces" or "jet bundles".

Comment: For any ring $A$, the quotient map $A \to A / \sqrt{0} = A_{\operatorname{red}}$ induces a homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec} A_{\operatorname{red}} \to \operatorname{Spec} A$. So the prime spectrum as a topological space does not see any non-reducedness.